# Aligning tick marks on an Area Chart with String X-Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, salesforce-lightning

I am building an area chart using the D3 Library, and I used their [area chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/area-chart) example to help me construct it. However, I am not using dates as along the x-axis, instead I am using Strings, so I tried using their [bar chart](https://observablehq.com/@d3/bar-chart) example to help me handle the xAxis and its values.

Due to this, though, my x axis tick marks are "centered" between two value points, rather than being left aligned (see image below).

[image: Sample Area Chart]

When I tried using the area chart example to construct the xAxis, I was not seeing any area being filled or any data points along the xAxis.

How can I move the tick marks to be aligned directly on the data point rather than centered between two different data points?

Here is what my code looks like when constructing the graph":

```
    sampleAreaData = [
        {"month": "Jun. 2018", "value": "2"},
        {"month": "Jul. 2018", "value": "12"},
        {"month": "Aug. 2018", "value": "33"},
        {"month": "Sept. 2018", "value": "100"},
        {"month": "Oct. 2018", "value": "150"},
        {"month": "Nov. 2018", "value": "368"},
        {"month": "Dec. 2018", "value": "404"},
        {"month": "Jan. 2019", "value": "482"},
        {"month": "Feb. 2019", "value": "559"},
    ]

    initializeSampleAreaGraph() {
        // Variables
        const svg = d3.select(this.template.querySelector('svg.sampleAreaGraph'));
        const width = this.svgSampleAreaWidth;
        const height = this.svgSampleAreaHeight;
        const margin = ({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30});
        const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(this.sampleAreaData.map(d => d.month))
            .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(this.sampleAreaData, d => d.value)]).nice()
            .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
        const xAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
        const yAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
            .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                .text(this.sampleAreaData.month));
        const area = d3.area()
            .x(d => x(d.month))
            .y0(y(0))
            .y1(d => y(d.value));

        // SVG Construction
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .datum(this.sampleAreaData)
            .attr("d", area)
        svg.append("g")
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(yAxis);
        return svg.node();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few things you could improve. TL;DR; the code below.

d3.scaleBand will return the ticks in the middle of a band, as the name says.
The following image was shamelessly copied from the [d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band-scales):
[image]

As you can see, the purpose of the scaleBand is split the axis in even bands.

Since you already have some kind of temporal information, you can try to parse it with `Date.parse(d.month)` and pass this information to build your domain.

I modified your snippet so it works in the preview and commented your code for a few other improvements.

```js
var sampleAreaData = [
        {"month": "Jun. 2018", "value": "2"},
        {"month": "Jul. 2018", "value": "12"},
        {"month": "Aug. 2018", "value": "33"},
        {"month": "Sept. 2018", "value": "100"},
        {"month": "Oct. 2018", "value": "150"},
        {"month": "Nov. 2018", "value": "368"},
        {"month": "Dec. 2018", "value": "404"},
        {"month": "Jan. 2019", "value": "482"},
        {"month": "Feb. 2019", "value": "559"},
    ];

    function initializeSampleAreaGraph() {
        // Variables
        // const svg = d3.select(this.template.querySelector('svg.sampleAreaGraph')); // no need to select a selection. d3.select is the same as a querySelector.
        const svg = d3.select('svg.sampleAreaGraph');
        const width = 500;
        const height = 500;
        const margin = ({top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30});
        const xScale = d3.scaleTime() // changed this to scaleBand
            .domain(d3.extent(sampleAreaData, function(d) { return Date.parse(d.month) })) // d3.extent return an array with min and max values
            .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(sampleAreaData, d => d.value)])
            .nice()
            .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
        const xAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`)
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));
        const yAxis = g => g
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
            .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
            .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
                .attr("x", 3)
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                .text(sampleAreaData.month));
        
      const area = d3.area(sampleAreaData)
            .x(d => xScale(Date.parse(d.month))) // pass a valid date number
            .y0(yScale(0))
            .y1(d => yScale(d.value));

        // SVG Construction
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .datum(this.sampleAreaData)
            .attr("d", area)
        svg.append("g")
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(yAxis);
        return svg.node();
    }

initializeSampleAreaGraph();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="900" height="500" class="sampleAreaGraph"></svg>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As stated in my question, I will not be using a Date, I will be using a string. While I see you convert my string into a Date in the `scaleTime()` piece, it is not guaranteed that my string will be convertible into a string. 

As for the selection of the SVG, I am using this in a salesforce web component and that is how you have to select SVG's.

Comment: You will have to define a pattern for your month property. Even if you work with something generic like scaleLinear() you should have some sort of pattern so you can sort things out. This pattern should be specified in your question.

Comment: Okay, So I went ahead and decided I'll only use these graphs if they correlate to a date, so I changed the `Month` to something like `2018-12-01`, `2019-01-01`, etc. But now my x axis lists them out like: `..., November, December, 2019, February, ...` How do you get it to display the whole date?

Comment: Oh, and also, your code snippet doesn't work. No graph appears

Comment: I'm seeing the graph right now. Works on my side :)